# Super newbie problems with NoMethod, nilClass in Rails 3.2.13

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

Another newbie question: I need help correctly setting defaults to my sick_days, sick_days_used, vacation_days, and vacation_days_used attributes to zero. I think they're defaulting to nil and crash my app when creating new employees.

Here's is the error I was getting:

> ## NoMethodError in Employees#index
>
> Showing /Users/ryrythefrenchfry/rails_projects/time_tracker/app/views/employees/index.html.erb where line #24 raised:
>
> undefined method `-' for nil:NilClass
> Extracted source (around line #24):

```
21:     <td><%= employee.first_name + " " + employee.last_name %></td>
22:     <td><%= employee.hire_date %></td>
23:     <td></td>
24:     <td><%= employee.remaining_sick_days %></td>
25:     <td></td>
26:     <td><%= employee.remaining_vacation_days %></td>
27:     <td></td>
```

Here's my model:

```
  class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :employee_id, :first_name, :hire_date, :last_name, :sick_days, :vacation_days, :sick_days_used, :vacation_days_used

   def remaining_sick_days
      sick_days - sick_days_used
   end

   def remaining_vacation_days
      vacation_days - vacation_days_used
   end
 end
```

Thank you for your generosity in helping out this mangy code-monkey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the value of sick_days in your Employee object is nil. This is probably because it was never initialized when you created a User object.

Comment: Yes, this was the case. I still had a few Employees hiding in the database with nil attributes. Zapped them, and we're good. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, `sick_days` is nil. You can read the error as "the object on the left-hand side of the minus sign is nil."

You could try something like this:

```
def remaining_sick_days
   if sick_days.nil?
     0
   else 
     sick_days - sick_days_used
   end
end
```

Comment: As an additional note, you could shorten that code by using the ternary operator. Personally, I choose not to just because I feel the ternary operator doesn't read well.

Comment: Thank you! I found out the reason it was still spitting out errors was because apparently I still had a few Employees hiding in the database with nil attributes. I destroyed them, and I'm using a validates :presence to make sure I'm not able to make a new employee with nil attributes again.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have sick_days specified. I would recomend you to use gem pry for that: http://railscasts.com/episodes/280-pry-with-rails and in you code:

```
   def remaining_sick_days
      binding.pry
      sick_days - sick_days_used
   end
```